# Strange behavior in packed Ruby strings

Tags: ruby, string, encoding

I'm confused by some ruby behavior. Look at the following code:

```
[127].pack("C") == "\x7f"   # => true
```

This makes sense. Now:

```
[128].pack("C")             # => "\x80"
"\x80"                      # => "\x80"
[128].pack("C") == "\x80"   # => false
```

The [pack option "C"](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-pack) stands for `8-bit unsigned (unsigned char)`, which should be fine to store a value of `128`. Also both strings print the same thing, so why are they not equal? Does this have something to do with encoding stuff?

I'm on ruby 2.0.0p247.

Comment: For me both are showing `true`...

Comment: The last one is `false` for me on `ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27 revision 41674) [x86_64-linux]`

Comment: I'm on 2.0.0p247, added it to the question.

Comment: Seems to be locale dependent. In `LC_ALL=en_US.utf8 irb` I get false for the 128/x80 comparison but in `LC_ALL=C irb` I get true. Tested on ruby 1.9.3p194, though, not 2.0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is false because the encodings differ:

```
[128].pack("C").encoding
#=> #<Encoding:ASCII-8BIT>
"\x80".encoding
#=> #<Encoding:UTF-8>
```

(using `ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27 revision 41674) [x86_64-linux]`)

In ruby 2.0 the default encoding for strings is UTF-8, but somehow `pack` returns an ASCII 8-Bit encoded string.

#### Why is  `[127].pack('C') == "\x79"` true then?

However, `[127].pack('C') == "\x79"` is `true`, because for the code points `0` to `127` ASCII and UTF-8 do not differ. This is considered by ruby's string comparison (have a look at [the rubinius source code](https://github.com/rubinius/rubinius/blob/master/kernel/common/string.rb#L96)):

```
def ==(other)
  [...]

  return false unless @num_bytes == other.bytesize
  return false unless Encoding.compatible?(self, other)
  return @data.compare_bytes(other.__data__, @num_bytes, other.bytesize) == 0
end
```

<sub>The [mri c-source](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/string.c#L2410) is similar, but harder to understand.</sub>

We observe, that the comparison checks for a compatible encoding. Let's try that:

```
Encoding.compatible?([127].pack("C"), "\x79") #=> #<Encoding:ASCII-8BIT>
Encoding.compatible?([128].pack("C"), "\x80") #=> nil
```

We see that beginning with code point 128 the comparison returns `false` even when both strings are made of the same bytes.

Comment: For me both are `true`.. Don't know why so mismatch ? :(

Comment: That seems to be it. `[128].pack("C").force_encoding("utf-8") == "\x80"` or `[128].pack("C") == "\x80".force_encoding("ascii-8bit")` returns `true`.

Comment: Arup: maybe your default encoding is not URF-8? Which ruby version do you use?

Comment: Isn't this a (specifcation) bug? Would someone one to file this as a bug to Ruby core? Or should I?

Comment: Right, at least it is not specified in the documentation which encoding `pack` should return. And UTF-8 should be the default.

Comment: Okay, I will file it.

Comment: Is that so? Generally `pack` will return something binary. I think ASCII is a better fit than UTF8 for that. I guess the correct fix would be converting the `"\x80"` literal to ascii like `"\x80".b`.

Comment: Okay, then I will not file it. But I didn't know that strings with the same content but with different encodings count as different. Is this the normal behaviour elsewhere?

Comment: I'm starting to thing the issue is not the different encoding but that ruby tries to convert them to the same one.

Comment: Regardless, it should probably be in the spec that `pack` returns an ASCII string.

Comment: @tessi I get [127].pack("C").encoding as <Encoding:ASCII-8BIT> and \x7f".encoding as <Encoding:UTF-8> then how come [127].pack("C") == "\x7f" returns true? I am using ruby 1.9.p327

Comment: @Sandeep my answer to your comment was too long, so I updated my original answer. Hope the update answers your question :)

Answer (score 1):

In Ruby 1.9, the default source file encoding is `US-ASCII`. While starting from Ruby 2.0, the default encoding has changed to `UTF-8`. String literals like `"\x80"` are always encoded using the encoding of the source file that contains them.

However, the encoding of `[128].pack("C")` is `ASCII-8BIT`.

So `[128].pack("C") == "\x80"` is `false` in Ruby 2.0 while `true` in Ruby 1.9

Putting `#coding:some_encoding` in the first line of source file (or just after the shebang) can change the default source code encoding.

```
#coding:ascii
puts([128].pack("C") == "\x80")
```

Output `true` in Ruby 2.0 as well.

Comment: while `true` in Ruby 1.9.. I think you mean.. :) :)